# How to show images on doughnut chart slice?

Tags: image, vue.js, svg, d3.js

I have a project where I need to display a doughnut chart. For every slice in the chart there is a corresponding icon in the legend. This icon should also been shown on the slice itself inside the chart.

I have found a working example online on how to display images on doughnut charts: [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/88t18rqg/6/). I have tried to implement this solution into my own project. The images get loaded in and when I inspect the SVG each path node(slice) contains an image element with the correct image. But the images don't show up on the graph.

This is the code i am running atm. If you have some pointers on how to improve my overall code then you're welcome to do so. I am still new to D3.JS and learning a lot about it at the moment:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="p-3 flex flex-col" id="one">
          <div class="w-full flex-1">
            <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          new Vue({
            el: '#one',
            data: {
              type: Array,
              required: true,
            },  mounted() {
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var width = 450;
        var height = 450;
        var margin = 1;
        var image_width = 32;
        var image_height = 32;
        
        var data = [
            {
              key: "One",
              value: 20,
              icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
            },
            {
              key: "Two",
              value: 30,
              icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
            },
            {
              key: "Three",
              value: 10,
              icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
            },
            {
              key: "Four",
              value: 15,
              icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
            }
          ]
        // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.

        // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    var svg = d3
                .select('#my_dataviz')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .append('g')
                .attr(
                  'transform',
                  'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
                );

        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

        // set the color scale
        var color = d3
          .scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(
            data.map(function(d) {
              return d["key"];
            })
          )
          .range(["#206BF3"]);

        // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
        var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
          return d[1];
        });

        var data_ready = pie(
          data.map(function(d) {
            return [d["key"], d["value"], d["icon"]];
          })
        );

        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3
          .arc()
          .outerRadius(100)
          .innerRadius(50);

        console.log(arc);

        // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
        var paths = svg
          .selectAll("whatever")
          .data(data_ready)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("d", d => {
            return arc(d);
          })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.data[0]);
          })
          .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
          .style("stroke-width", "2px")
          .style("opacity", 0.7);

        paths
          .append("svg:image")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
            var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
            return "translate(" + width / 2 + x + "," + height + y + ")";
          })
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return d.data[2];
          })
          .attr("width", image_width)
          .attr("height", image_height);

        paths.on("mouseover", e => {
          this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(e.currentTarget), 1);
        });
        paths.on("mouseout", e => {
          var thisPath = d3.select(e.currentTarget);
          if (!thisPath.classed("clicked")) {
            this.pathAnim(radius, thisPath, 0);
          }
        });
      },
      methods: {
        pathAnim(radius, path, dir) {
          switch (dir) {
            case 0:
              path
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .ease(d3.easeBounce)
                .attr(
                  "d",
                  d3
                    .arc()
                    .innerRadius(100)
                    .outerRadius(50)
                );
              path.style("fill", "#206BF3");
              break;

            case 1:
              path.transition().attr(
                "d",
                d3
                  .arc()
                  .innerRadius(50)
                  .outerRadius(110)
              );
              path.style("fill", "white");
              break;
          }
        }
      }
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<path>` element cannot contain an `<image>`. Instead of that, use the data to create `<g>` elements and append both the `<path>` and the `<image>` to them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="p-3 flex flex-col" id="one">
    <div class="w-full flex-1">
      <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#one',
      data: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
      },
      mounted() {
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var width = 450;
        var height = 450;
        var margin = 1;
        var image_width = 32;
        var image_height = 32;

        var data = [{
            key: "One",
            value: 20,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          },
          {
            key: "Two",
            value: 30,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          },
          {
            key: "Three",
            value: 10,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          },
          {
            key: "Four",
            value: 15,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          }
        ]
        // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.

        // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
        var svg = d3
          .select('#my_dataviz')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height)
          .append('g')
          .attr(
            'transform',
            'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
          );

        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

        // set the color scale
        var color = d3
          .scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(
            data.map(function(d) {
              return d["key"];
            })
          )
          .range(["#206BF3"]);

        // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
        var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
          return d[1];
        });

        var data_ready = pie(
          data.map(function(d) {
            return [d["key"], d["value"], d["icon"]];
          })
        );

        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3
          .arc()
          .outerRadius(100)
          .innerRadius(50);

        // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
        var g = svg
          .selectAll("whatever")
          .data(data_ready)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
            var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
            return "translate(" + width / 2 + x + "," + height + y + ")";
          });

        g.append("path")
          .attr("d", d => {
            return arc(d);
          })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.data[0]);
          })
          .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
          .style("stroke-width", "2px")
          .style("opacity", 0.7);

        g.append("svg:image")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
            var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
            return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
          })
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
            return d.data[2];
          })
          .attr("width", image_width)
          .attr("height", image_height);

        g.on("mouseover", e => {
          this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(e.currentTarget), 1);
        });
        g.on("mouseout", e => {
          var thisPath = d3.select(e.currentTarget);
          if (!thisPath.classed("clicked")) {
            this.pathAnim(radius, thisPath, 0);
          }
        });
      },
      methods: {
        pathAnim(radius, path, dir) {
          switch (dir) {
            case 0:
              path
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .ease(d3.easeBounce)
                .attr(
                  "d",
                  d3
                  .arc()
                  .innerRadius(100)
                  .outerRadius(50)
                );
              path.style("fill", "#206BF3");
              break;

            case 1:
              path.transition().attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(50)
                .outerRadius(110)
              );
              path.style("fill", "white");
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you add both the path and the image to a <g> element doesn't that kill the mouseover transition I added? It isn't working anymore in the code snippet.

Comment: I have one more question. Do you actually know how to display this with a local image e.a `.attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return "img/" + d.data[2];})`

Comment: @Stephen I can't understand your problem from the comment only. I suggest you post a new question, with the relevant details.

Comment: @GerardoFutado Here is a link to my new question with detailed explenation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520519/d3-js-how-to-append-local-image

Answer (score 2):

I've updated @GerardoFurtado's code. I just moved the events to the `path`s and added `pointer-events: none` for images. Transitions work well.

```css
g image {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="p-3 flex flex-col" id="one">
    <div class="w-full flex-1">
      <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#one',
      data: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
      },
      mounted() {
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var width = 450;
        var height = 450;
        var margin = 1;
        var image_width = 32;
        var image_height = 32;

        var data = [{
            key: "One",
            value: 20,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          },
          {
            key: "Two",
            value: 30,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          },
          {
            key: "Three",
            value: 10,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          },
          {
            key: "Four",
            value: 15,
            icon: "http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png"
          }
        ]
        // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.

        // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
        var svg = d3
          .select('#my_dataviz')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height)
          .append('g')
          .attr(
            'transform',
            'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
          );

        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

        // set the color scale
        var color = d3
          .scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(
            data.map(function(d) {
              return d["key"];
            })
          )
          .range(["#206BF3"]);

        // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
        var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
          return d[1];
        });

        var data_ready = pie(
          data.map(function(d) {
            return [d["key"], d["value"], d["icon"]];
          })
        );

        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3
          .arc()
          .outerRadius(100)
          .innerRadius(50);

        // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
        var g = svg
          .selectAll("whatever")
          .data(data_ready)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          /* I commented this lines and nothing changed.
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
            var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
            return "translate(" + width / 2 + x + "," + height + y + ")";
          });
          */

        g.append("path")
          .attr("d", d => {
            return arc(d);
          })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.data[0]);
          })
          .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
          .style("stroke-width", "2px")
          .style("opacity", 0.7)
          .on("mouseover", e => {
            console.log(this)
            this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(e.currentTarget), 1);
          })
          .on("mouseout", e => {
            var thisPath = d3.select(e.currentTarget);
            if (!thisPath.classed("clicked")) {
              this.pathAnim(radius, thisPath, 0);
            }
          });

        g.append("svg:image")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
            var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
            return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
          })
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
            return d.data[2];
          })
          .attr("width", image_width)
          .attr("height", image_height);
      },
      methods: {
        pathAnim(radius, path, dir) {
          switch (dir) {
            case 0:
              path
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .ease(d3.easeBounce)
                .attr(
                  "d",
                  d3
                  .arc()
                  .innerRadius(100)
                  .outerRadius(50)
                );
              path.style("fill", "#206BF3");
              break;

            case 1:
              path.transition().attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(50)
                .outerRadius(110)
              );
              path.style("fill", "white");
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I run the code snippet the console in Chrome still gives one eror: `d3.v6.js:1720 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected ')', "….593376811331936,45057.361070055…".`. The animation is working.

Comment: You may have made a mistake copying the code. There is no any error in this code.

Comment: When I open the snippet in Chrome and I open the console window(F12) I get this error.

Comment: In Firefox I get 0 errors. But in Chrome I do.

Comment: yeah I see. See my update please. I removed transform from outer g.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem completely! Sorry for my questions I am very new to D3.JS and I find it hard to get it started.

Comment: I have one more question. Do you actually know how to display this with a local image e.a `.attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return "img/" + d.data[2];})`?

Comment: Check out this example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image you can use like in normal ``<img>` tag.

Comment: Here is a new question with detailed explenation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520519/d3-js-how-to-append-local-image