# D3.js How to append local image

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this project where I need to add local images. At this point it is possible to add images that are located on a URL using svg images and xlink:href.

But the images I am using are located in a local folder inside my project `src/assets/img` or `@/assets/img`(ES6 import using at ('@')).

But I cannot get the images to load in. If I add the src attribute to the image the src is being set to `http://localhost:8080/@/assets/img/arrow.svg` and not to the actual source of the image in the project.

If I inspect the DOM tree in the Chrome console a normal img would look like this:

[image]

While the img that is being appended by D3js is not being inserted correctly and when I hover over the src it shows: `http://localhost:8080/@/assets/img/arrow.svg`

[image]

The `d.data[2]` contains the name of the actual image e.g. 'arrow.svg' I have also tried to change `src` to `xlink:src`:

```
g.append("img")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
        var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
        return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
      })
      .attr("src", function(d) {
        return "@/assets/img/" + d.data[2];
      })
      .attr("width", image_width)
      .attr("height", image_height);
```

This is a working example when the images are located on a URL:

```
g.append("svg:image")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
        var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
        return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
      })
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d.data[2];
      })
      .attr("width", image_width)
      .attr("height", image_height);
```

Comment: Are you attempting to use an html `img` tag or an SVG `image` tag?  You seem to be switching back and forth in your code snippet.  Also, your question really seems to be how can I serve local content from my web-server?  Which web-server are you using?  Have you tried navigating to `https://localhost:8080/src/assets/img/arrow.svg` to see if the images will load outside your javascript code?

Comment: I just wanne show the img It does not matter what type of img tag it is. I don't wanne show content from my web server. The images are located in the Vue project in the `assets/img` folders.  But when I put the location of those images in the src tag of my img the source that gets rendered in html is ``https://localhost:8080/src/assets/img/arrow.svg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try the following and see if it works:

```
.attr("src", function(d) {
    const imagePath = require("@/assets/img/" + d.data[2]);
    return imagePath;
  })
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error: "Syntax Error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (142:4)"

Comment: I am glad that helped you.

Comment: For people who have the same issue in the futute: You can use an `svg:image` in this example but you need to just change `src` to  `href`

Answer (score 0):

```
  .attr("src", function(d) {
    return "@/assets/img/" + d.data[2];
```

aren't you returning the wrong src?

Comment: This source is the same when using on a normal img src.